# github actions/checkout@v3 will delete unwatched file on the server

Tags: ubuntu, github-actions

I'm using github action to auto deploy to unbuntu digitalocean server.

my yaml file

```
name: Continuous Deployment

on:
    push:
        branches:
            - main

jobs:
    deployment:
        runs-on: self-hosted
        steps:
            - name: Checkout main branch
              uses: actions/checkout@v3

            - name: Setup Node.js
              uses: actions/setup-node@v3
              with:
                  node-version: '16.x'

            - name: Install dependencies
              run: npm ci

            - name: Restart server
              run: npm run restart
```

the folder structure on my server

```
index.ts
someMiddleware.ts
.env
```

my local folder structure

```
index.ts
someMiddleware.ts
.env
```

My gitignore

```
.env
```

So the problem is, my `.env` on the server got deleted everytime the github action runs. I had to manually add the `.env` to server but it keeps getting delete by the github actions/checkout@v3

My question is, how to config github action so it won't delete unwatched files like the `.env` in this case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action performs `git clean -ffdx` by default. This is what's removing the file. Using the following prevents that:

```yaml
- name: Checkout main branch
  uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    clean: false
```

This is documented as "Whether to execute `git clean -ffdx && git reset --hard HEAD` before fetching".